# How to use angle brackets in php email header

Tags: php, html

if I`m using the < (angle brackets) in email headers,and html is stopped rendering like i am using 
 than it is showing 
 as a text not rendering as a html.

```
$headers1 = "From: Example  <example.p@email.com/>" . "\r\n";
```

I tried many solutions like i have also used &lt and $gt but still its not working. Please help me.

Comment: you should try below post , it will work ..or let me know

Answer (score 2):

There is no forward slash in end of the email address. And you shouldn't add headers into your message, you should set headers as a different parameter. So they won't affect your content.

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: Example Site <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: No i used what you are saying but still not working :(

Comment: Yooo Working ! Thanx Alot :)

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this :

```
$headers = 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
```

for details visit the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/>` use `>`

```
$headers1 = "From: Example  <example.p@email.com>" . "\r\n";
```